Why my Java Spring app crashes If I launch it with "-XDebug" and "-Xrunjdwp" flags simultaneously?
I have Java Spring app that can be launched with
./mvnw spring-boot:run
I want to debug this app, so I'm trying to launch it with flags
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-XDebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
And get error:
Unrecognized option: -XDebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
But when I'm trying to run same app with flags "XDebug" and "Xrunjdwp" separately:
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-XDebug"
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
It launches without any errors.
Why I get error when trying to use both flags in same time? My obvious guess is that by some reason Java treats "-XDebug -Xrunjdwp" as one flag, but I don't see what is the reason of this.

-XDebug and -Xrunjdw are older debugging options that have been replaced since the days of Java 6. Unless you are stuck using Java 5 since 2006 you should be using the modern debug arguments: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000.

Thanks, replacing two flags with one flag -agentlib:jdwp helped, so I marked your answer as correct.
But honestly it's just workaround and not solution of problem with arguments. Why Spring works normally if I'm provide arguments one by one but crashes when I'm provide two arguments? What if in the future I will need to provide two arguments by reasons another than debugging?
